# A sketching tool would be very useful

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I basic sketching tool to quickly draw out graphs / concepts etc. along the lines of Balsamiq markups would be really useful. It would be doubly useful if people answering questions could access the same sketch and add their own information. Having to draw it up and then upload it is just a bit of a pain right now.

Comment: I guess this is a feature request that is usefull for a lot of stackexchange sites! Maybe a crosspost to meta.stackoverflow is justified?

Comment: I am not sure but I think the devs monitor all the meta sites. So, if you tag a qn with feature-request it will get their attention.

Comment: Please correct the spelling in the question title?

Comment: [status-declined] clarification: A feature like this would be a big deal, and useful on many other sites. Consider elaborating and refining this feature request and posting it on [metase] if it's still of interest to you.

Comment: Interesting! I personally use inkscape and export PNGs. It isn't "inline", but imho a subset of Balsamiq without controls could be a welcome embedable addition.